# Socket Programming Failed in NAT Networks

Tags: c#, sockets

I am doing projects using sockets,actually it runs in our environment without fail
(LAN).

When I try to run it in the client side which employs the **NAT** in their environment
my program fails(i.e) unable to connect to the server through the client program I created.

How to alter the program ? there is a Enum called `SocketOption` will it helps to solve my problem?

i want to transfer from a NATed Computer to a NATed Computer in the same network

want to set bounty for this question

Comment: you should fix the layout of your message :P it seems the message of Hi is put as "code", fails? how does it fail do you get a exception or some thing?

Comment: Where is the client and where is the server? Connecting from inside NAT-ed network to server on public internet should work. Connecting from public internet to server inside NAT-ed network should NOT work unless explicit port-forwarding is setup. BTW, socket options have nothing to do with this, it's the routing that gets you.

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov i agree with what you mentioned, but how does yahoo and skype  etc do it?

Comment: Client behind NAT connects out to the server with TCP and keeps that connection active for all event notification like incoming calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Searching for sometime , found this information

NAT is not something you can usually pro grammatically control.  (There is UPNP, but I've never seen it work.)  If you need to connect a client to a server which is behind a NAT you must manually configure the NAT device (router) to do port forwarding.

**Link:**
http://blogs.msdn.com/ncl/archive/2009/07/27/end-to-end-connectivity-with-nat-traversal-.aspx

Comment: This may be an old post, but in the case of alot of software and video games, how do they pull it off. Im on a LAN, and I want to know how to make server/client software work through a LAN.